# The second and Third Options for the Dropdown are either disabled or not being highlighted

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

The second and the third options are disabled, not been highlighted when hovered over and also do not change to pointer. I didn't use any library, used useState for their states and an Onclick function to toggle the dropdown. I don't know why the other two are disabled. Kindly assist(ReactJS AND Tailwind CSS)

```
const ButtonDropDown = () => {
  const [isDropdown, setIsDropdown] = useState(false);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsDropdown(!isDropdown);
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <button 
      onClick={toggleDropdown}
      className="rounded-[5px] px-[1.4rem] py-[.5rem] bg-buttonColor text-buttonFont font-inter text-sm font-semibold leading-5 tracking-[0.28px]">
        Export <ArrowDown className="inline-flex" />
      </button>
      {isDropdown && (
        <div className="absolute right-0 mt-2 py-2 w-40 bg-white border rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          {/* Add your dropdown options here */}
          <Link to="" className="block px-4 py-2 font-inter text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 text-center">PDF</Link>
          <Link to="" className="block px-4 py-2 font-inter text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 text-center hover:cursor-pointer">CSV</Link>
          <Link to="" className="block px-4 py-2 font-inter text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 text-center hover:cursor-pointer">Option 3</Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

When clicking on the button, options are to show but first option is showing correctly and highlighting correctly. The other two are not.
I have asked Chatgpt but not able to resolve this.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHRRt.png)

Comment: https://react-tailwind-1rhcan.stackblitz.io/. I tried to reproduce your issue but I think it still works as expected. You can go here and check if any difference between your tailwind settings and mine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. I have seen where it is coming from, one of the components is blocking the second and third options from being highlighted.